# Input type number should start again from min value with up arrow and max value with down arrow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

I have number input,

```
<input type="number" name="start" id="start" value="0" min="0" max="24" />
```

so, i want functionality like when i click up arrow till max value(24 here) reaches after that it should start again from 0 and same when reaches limit till min value(0 here) with down arrow, after that it should start with 24.

And also same should work with keyup and keydown arrow.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this

```js
function myFunction(){
if(document.getElementById("start").value == 25){
 document.getElementById("start").value = 0;
}
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="start" id="start" value="0" min="0" max="25" onchange="myFunction()" />
```

If you want to do the same thing if number hits 0 then use this code:

```js
function myFunction(){
if(document.getElementById("start").value == 25){
 document.getElementById("start").value = 0;
}
if(document.getElementById("start").value == -1){
 document.getElementById("start").value = 24;
}
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="start" id="start" value="0" min="-1" max="25" onchange="myFunction()" />
```

Comment: but its not with down arrow click revers the value `24>23>22...`

Comment: you mean you want it when it hits 0 get to 24?

Comment: yes on downarrow press in 0 value its go with `24` again  `min value(0 here) with down arrow, after that it should start with 24.` refer OP question

Comment: if(document.getElementById("start").value == 0){
 document.getElementById("start").value = 24;
}

Comment: just add that line inside function

Comment: your answer only for up button.not with down button click. .from `0` down button click its again start from 24

Comment: Nice..now it be perfect...+1

Comment: For what it's worth, this does not work with a step > 1. Changing the min to -1 breaks the step.